# Is the proof of those 2 questions the same?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, solution-verification

The first question is:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence in a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$. Prove that

for each $y \in \mathbb{H}$, there is a subsequence $\{ x_{n_{k}}\}$ such that the sequence $\{ \langle x_{n_{k}},y\rangle\}$ converges.

While the second question is:

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be an unbounded sequence in Hilbert $\mathcal{H}.$ Prove that there exists a vector $x \in \mathcal{H}$ such that the sequence $\{\langle x_{n}, x \rangle\}$ is unbounded.

Is the proof of those 2 questions the same? as I know the proof of the first one.

Comment: For the second problem, just take x=0. In an arbitrary Hilbert space, we can't do any better than that.

Comment: @Quoka the second problem is an inner product also, I am sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: Let $(\cdot, \cdot)$ denote the inner product on $\mathcal{H}$.

As Quoka said, the only thing you can do for the second one in general is take $x=0$. First it is clear that this works and so proves your proposition. Why is this our only choice in general? For example, in a finite dimensional Hilbert space, let $e_1,...,e_n$ a basis. Consider the sequence $e_1,e_2,...,e_n, 2e_1,2e_2,...,2e_n, 3e_1,...$. Then if $x \neq 0$ you can easily see that $(x,x_n)$ will be unbounded. You can even do this for any separable Hilbert space.

Edit: Originally said *bounded*.

Fixed answer: Suppose for every $x \in \mathcal{H}$, $(x,x_n)$ is bounded. Then for the linear functionals $\phi_{x_n}$ given by $\phi_{x_n}(y) = (y,x_n)$, we have for each $y \in \mathcal{H}$, $\sup_n |\phi_{x_n}(y)| < \infty$. Then by the uniform boundedness principle $\sup_n \|\phi_{x_n}\| < \infty$. But $\|\phi_{x_n}\| = \|x_n\|$, so $\sup_n \|x_n\| < \infty$. So $x_n$ is bounded.

Comment: So the 2 questions are unrelated?

Comment: Yes. The second question is a bit uninteresting really, so the only answer is just take $x=0$, which gives you a much better than bounded sequence: a constant, hence convergent, sequence.

Comment: oh sorry it was a typo … it should be unbounded.

Comment: Well that changes things...

Comment: Are they the same now? what about the theorem I mentioned ? is it useful now?

Comment: Is the second proposition correct in the finite dimensional case?

Comment: I do not understand the calculation of the norm in your third line from below. why $a_{j}e_{j}$ has norm square aroung it?

Comment: Added some more explanation.

Comment: In the same line I asked about before, I do not understand why $\infty > \|x\|^2 $? Also, I I do not understand in this statement  " hence by a standard result on convergent sums, $|a_j|^2 \to 0$." why we have convergent sums? and what is the "standard result " you are referring to? ….. could you clarify this please?

Comment: I can not see how $(x, x_{j}) = a_j$. should not it be $\sum_{j} a_{j} j$?

Comment: I realized I made a mistake. You will probably be best off asking your corrected question as a new question.

Comment: Alright, now the answer should be correct, of course I prove the contrapositive here.

Comment: So the 2 questions turned out to be the same question .... am I correct?

Comment: No, I would say they are fairly unrelated still. Note how the second one has nothing to do with convergence, only boundedness.

Comment: So the asked (second) question turned out to be correct .... correct?

Comment: Yes, I was wrong with the first answer. Convince yourself it is correct by reading the proof.

Comment: How is your $\phi_{x_{n}}(y)$ a real valued function? as it should be a linear functional  ..... is your $x_{n}$ fixed?

Comment: It isn’t. No reason it needs to be. It’s $\mathbb{C}$ valued.

Comment: If you are in a real Hilbert space, it is real valued. If you are in a complex Hilbert space, it is complex valued.

Comment: I think $x_{n}$ is taken as a constant in each step and so your $\phi $ is a function of $y$ only and so it is not ordered pair and so it is a real valued function if we are in $\mathbb{R}$ … am I correct? I think what confuses @Mathstupid is that you are writing it as an ordered pair.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion. I'm denoting inner product by $(\cdot, \cdot)$. A lot easier to typeset and is standard notation, but it is at variance with yours. I'll make a note of it.

Comment: Also does not every convergent sequence is bounded ? …. does not that give us a link between the 2 questions?

Comment: @Emptymind Exactly that is what confuses me. thanks!

Comment: @Emptymind You can try to look for a link or similarity between the two questions if you really want to, but ultimately the important thing is that we ***do not use*** the result (1) in the proof of (2).

Comment: But maybe we can use a similar proof to (1) in the proof of $(2).$

Comment: Why do you want a connection so much?

Comment: It was my original question in the post … to try to create a proof from another proof that I already know.

Comment: I think I've gotten my point across the best I can; these questions are effectively unrelated. One has to do with subsequential convergence which follows directly from a theorem in topology that gives that sequences in compact sets on metric spaces admit convergent subsequences. The other one follows from the uniform boundedness principle, which is a result on Banach spaces, having very little to do with topology. I don't believe any meaningful connection between the two exists.

Comment: okay I see your point @KeeferRowan  thank you very much for clarification ...let me ask you a question about your inner product ….. your dot product is with one factor kept constant …. am I correct? so, your $\phi_{x_{n}}(y) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} y_{n} x_{n}$ … am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106877/discussion-between-keefer-rowan-and-emptymind).